# How to get a non-null response on retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, response

//Main_Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView t1;
    Button b1;
    String one,key;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        t1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.but_click);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        peopleDetails();
    }

    public void peopleDetails()
    {

        Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        Apiservice service=retrofit.create(Apiservice.class);
        Call<Modelclass> call=service.peopleDetails();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Modelclass>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Modelclass> call, Response<Modelclass> response) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onresponse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                key=response.body().getKey();

                t1.setText(key.toString());


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Modelclass> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onfail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The above code throws a `NullPointerException`.

The I am using this url for requests:

   http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two

Comment: Post your error log

Comment: Post your logcat and also the ApiService class please.

Comment: this is my interface  public interface Apiservice {
    @GET("/two")
    Call<Modelclass> peopleDetails();
}

Comment: and this is error

Comment: does the Toast message show inside onResponse? You can comment out key = response.body().getKey(); & t1.setText(key.toString()); just check Toast is showing or not?

Comment: when i am not taking data into String variable then execution is goes in onresponse method.. toast message show onresponse,, but when i am taking data into variable.. then null comes in my variable.. and then null pointerexception occurs..

Comment: Show your model class

Comment: class Modelclass {

    private String one;
    private String key;
    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getOne() {
        return one;
    }

    public void setOne(String one) {
        this.one = one;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
}